# Middle of the page moves to the right when i change the page

Tags: css

I made a site with pictures and when i enter on the picture page and ...click on Next, Preview pictures the picture float to right. In IE work well but in Google Chrome, Mozilla,Safari ...the middle page float to right. 
I tried change in css but nothink .You can help me pls?
Thanks in advance !

The class "content" i put in header and the css code

```
body {
    /*background-color: none;
    border-radius: 25px;
    background-image:url('/images/gray_jean.png');*/
    background: #ffffff;
    color: #000000;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

.content {
    position:relative;
    margin:0 auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: center;
    width:100%;
    clear: both;
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your current code to this,

```
.content {
    margin:0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    width:100%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks - i put your lines but nothing when i add html {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}   and normal .content {
    margin:0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    width:100%;
}  it work super. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `position:relative;` from the `.content`.

```
.content {
  position:relative; // Remove this
}
```

And try, may be?

Comment: And call me, maybe? (Couldn't help it)

Comment: LoL. I don't know what to say.